# Error saving options of Bootstrap Free Template on MAMP Pro

Tags: themes, mamp-pro, impresspages

Does anybody have had this error while editing and saving the theme options?

```
[Mon Jul 13 17:15:34 2015] [error] [client ::1] 
FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server 
"/Applications/MAMP/fcgi-bin/php5.3.29.fcgi", 
referer: http://www.dasforschungsdock.local:8888/?ipDesignPreview=1
```

I have this error also in the untouched original theme and I am using the current MAMP Pro 3.3, no caching php activated, ExecCGI activated. 
The Apache is the up to date inside Yosemite.

The settings seem to be saved somehow, because they re-appear coming back to the options page, but they have no influence on the compiled css file.

Thank you!

Comment: I checked the ip_theme_storage table in the db and the values are there. 
Some values are used for compiling, some are not. 
Looks like the compilation is a kind of bottle neck here.

Answer (score 0):

Got this solved so far: 
The compilation of the less file takes pretty long on my MAcBook Pro late 2011 model.

I could compensate this changing MAMP setting like in this posting: 
https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4661/fastcgi-error-when-accessing-a-local-development-site-using-mamp-pro

The color problem was due to a "user mistake" - no actual problem at all.